# Cannot add dynamic data to Firebase RealtimeDatabase with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having this problem, but I cannot figure out why I can't add new items, or better, maybe I can add but the previous item is being substituted. Here is a video.

[image: Here is the video]

this is the code:

```
ZStack {
//...    
Button(action: {
                print(locali)
                Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
                    print(auth.currentUser?.email)
                    ref
                        .child("locali")
                        .child(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "no uid")
                        .setValue(["nomeLocale\(locali.count)" : nomeLocale])
                }
}, label: {
           //...
}
           //...
}
.onAppear {
          ref.child("locali").child(userID!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                print(snapshot)
                guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String : NSObject] else {
                    print("error with the guard first")
                    return
                }
                print(value)
                guard let nomeInValue = value["nomeLocale\(locali.count)"] as? String else {
                    print("error with the guard second")
                    return
                }
                print(nomeInValue)
                locali.append(nomeInValue)
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: The video is just too small.

Comment: @CPP_is_no_STANDARD I've seen I'm updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setValue` on a path in the database, all the existing data at that path is replaced with whatever you are passing in.

If you only want to [update whatever child properties/paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) you are passing in, use `updateChildValues` instead.